# how to get value if index contains certain value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains alot of keys and values. I can get any value using the index. But I dont have the full index, I have a part of it, would I be able to get the value based on a part of the index.

Example:

```
$arr = array("Index"->"MyValue");
```

`$arr["Index"]` will return `"MyValue"` but I need to do something like `$arr["dex"]` or `$arr["My Index"]`to return the same `"MyValue"`

Comment: you could probably get all available keys from the array (`array_keys`) and start the search from there, once found, now use it to point the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to find just those keys matching your condition:

```
$matches = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($key) { return false !== strpos($key, 'dex'); }, 
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

[See it live on 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/oH6FL)

Tweak the logic inside the closure to match the specific need. In this example, if the key does not contain 'dex', consider the key a match. Per the comment, to search for a key that contains a sub-string, or a key that itself is a sub-string, you can use:

```
function array_search_by_partial_key(array $array, $partial) {
    return array_filter(
        $array,
        function ($key) use ($partial) {
            return false !== strpos($key, $partial) || false !== strpos($partial, $key);
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
    );
}
```

This is just an elaboration the direct answer, made a bit more easy to use by wrapping in a function. [See it live on 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/o22aL)

Comment: thanks bishob, what about if I want to search the other way. I edited the question

Comment: `||` in another `strpos` and flip its argument order.

Comment: thank you, not sure what is wrong but I have created a function which takes the array the the key $k but the $k is not seen by the inner function. 
private function matchKeys($array,$k)
    {
        $matches = array_filter($array, function ($key) { return false !== strpos($key, $k) || false !== strpos($k,$key); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    }

Comment: Likely you need a `use` to import that key into the closure scope. I've elaborated my answer into a reusable function.

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` loop in the following form will allow you to inspect both the value *and* the key:

```
foreach( $my_array as $key => $value ) {
  // partial matching on $key here
}
```

For simple substring matching [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) would be preferable, but for more complex matching you may want [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).